# Issue with multiple levels ul li menu

Tags: html, css

I made a multiple levels menu by `ul` and `li`,but the second level text breaks in 2 lines like below picture :

[image]

**Note :** I can't use static width for second level menu (`li2 class`),because texts size is dynamic in this level and it can be 1 word or many words.

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <ul class="ul1">
            <li class="li1">home</li>
            <li class="li1">accessories
                    <ul class="ul2">
                        <li class="li2">cases and protectors
                            <ul class="ul3">
                                <li class="li3"><a href="#">case 1</a></li>
                                <li class="li3"><a href="#">case 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 0;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 48px;
}

.ul1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    display: table;
    height: 48px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.li1 {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 48px;
    float: right;
    border: solid 1px #FFF;
    position: relative;
}

    .li1:hover .ul2 {
        display: block;
    }

.ul2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffd800;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49px;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.li2 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 48px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 48px;
    background-color: #808080;
    display: block;
}
.ul3
{
    display:none;    
}
```

and here is a live [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lyodun6/),what am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, what do you try to achieve?

Comment: I'm going to achieve "cases and protectors" in a single line and stretched li for that line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick solution is to add `white-space: nowrap;` to element with class `.li2`:

> **nowrap**
>
> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks
>   (text wrapping) within text.

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 48px;
}
.ul1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  display: table;
  height: 48px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}
.li1 {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 48px;
  float: right;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
  position: relative;
}
.li1:hover .ul2 {
  display: block;
}
.ul2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffd800;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 49px;
  width: auto;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.li2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 48px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: #808080;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ul3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1">home</li>
    <li class="li1">accessories
      <ul class="ul2">
        <li class="li2">cases and protectors
          <ul class="ul3">
            <li class="li3"><a href="#">case 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="li3"><a href="#">case 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can fix the issue with the align adding `left: 0` and `overflow: hidden` and remove `right: 0`

**Reference**

[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)